# C++ What would be the fastest way to search and count for a specific element within a std::vector?

Tags: c++

How do we search for a specific element and count it within a std::vector? It MUST be fast. Please help, thank you.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Lets assume the Database is sorted (which it will be)
std::vector< std::string > Database( 3 );
Database.push_back( "Password123" );
Database.push_back( "HelloWorld!!!" );
Database.push_back( "HelloWorld!!!" );
//...

std::string Password = "HelloWorld!!!";

// Search and count Password?
// Should return true and 2
```

Oh and I heard indexing is slower than iterator. Is it true?

Comment: You can't beat linear time if your vector isn't sorted.

Comment: Well, you can't count specific elements without checking each element once at least. Thus the complexity of the most efficient solution will be O(n).

Comment: Okay, lets say it was sorted. How do we do it? :)

Comment: If it's sorted, call lower_bound + upper_bound then call distance?

Comment: Got it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)?

```
int num = std::count(Data.begin(), Data.end(), target);
```

But if this "MUST be fast", then you should consider sorting your vector before querying it, because then you can use faster approaches to counting (e.g. `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`).

Comment: I hope this is fast. Thanks. Also, how do we search for target?

Comment: What do you mean?  target is whatever it is that you want to count.

Comment: Oh, I am tripping. Thanks.

Comment: @ruben2020: It works for any type that has an appropriate overload for `operator==`.

Comment: And for types that don't have `operator==`, or if it doesn't have the semantics you want, there is `std::count_if`.